# Horizontal alignment - MiniPage

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I can´t get the minipages title to align with one another, as you can see in the images. Already tried align*.
Thanks for the help!

```
\documentclass

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}

\cvsection{Software}

\cvtag{Excel}

\cvtag{Word}

\cvtag{Eviews}

\cvtag{LaTex}

\cvtag{Haskell}

\cvtag{Access}

\cvtag{R}

\cvtag{PowerPoint}

\end{minipage}

\hfill

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}

\cvsection{Languages}

\begin{itemize}

    
\item Portuguese (Native)
    
\item English (Fluent)

\end{itemize}

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  A compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of the two minipages as well as a short description of what "align with each other"  means specifically would be really helpful here. Please edit your qurstion to include such a MWE. (I assume the image currently shown in your question is not the one you intended to include. Aparently there currently is a network-wide issue with wrong images apprearing in posts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359772)

Comment: Since the images aren't displaying as expected, you should post your code. Wait, you should *always* paste code. Can you do that? Your code should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and allows us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and replicate your issue. Nothing extra, just the essentials to replicate the issue.

Comment: the code isn´t appearing as it's supposed to, i used \documentclass and \end{document} , but it stayed like that, which is very weird looking.

Comment: Which documentclass are you currently using?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: [I am getting the wrong image when uploading a picture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359772/168244) Or, *ask a question* and post an image as well. Then, and only then will you see what's going on. :D

Comment: @Werner oops!!!!

Comment: [10pt,a4paper,academicons]{altacv}

Comment: @JoãoFelício so I see the image upload on site is broken (I am sure they will fix it soon) but in any case please always add _code_ not images, it is hard to debug an image.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yeah, i'll do it in the future

Comment: @JoãoFelício do you need that documentclass to show your problem? You say you are asking about minipage alignment so can you make a simple 1-page document using `article` class that shows the problem, then people can debug for you

Comment: I guess, you want both minipages to be top aligned. In that case, use `\beg{minipage}[t]` for both minipages.

Comment: pleas take care of your code. As you post it the example can not be run (missing `\documentclass` name, missing `\begin{document}` ) and the two minipages will be vertically aligned as youhave blank lines (paragraph break) between them, does your real document have blank lines there?

Comment: @leandriis Yes, it worked like a charm. Thanks!